# How to call a component attracted by an onPress method?

Tags: react-native, react-router

I'm doing a project with react native where I already have a navigation, I use bottomTabBavigator, 
defined in the routes.js file.One of these routes leads to a page that contains a map, MapPage.js.

In this screen I would like to call another screen, according to a user click, I am including a behavior in Map Maker.(Something like stacknavigator)

```
<Marker key={index}
                coordinate={{
                  latitude: maker.coordinate[0].latitude,
                  longitude: maker.coordinate[0].longitude
                }}
                title={maker.companyName}
                description={'Ambev Code: ' + maker.ambevCode}

                onPress={() => this.state?.idMaker==maker.id ? this.callFactory() : this.setState({idMaker:maker.id})}

              >

              </Marker>
```

In the onPress () method, I perform a validation, which does not suit the question, and call a function callFactory (), I would like this function to call a screen (something similar to the stacknavigator style), but I am not finding any documentation on how to do this.

In practice, I need that when the user clicks a second time on the Maker, a function (that I can already do) is called that calls up another screen (that I couldn't do).

How can I do it?

Comment: why don't you use StackNavigator and when the function callFactory() is called, navigate it to the screen that you wanted?

Comment: @displayname Because I don't know how to use two browsers. I do not know if you will create a stack or the Navigator browser on routes.js or only on this page, that no case will be the only one that will use navigation. I tried to do two ways, but they were not right.